# Where I can find API Key to Raw Export Data

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with authorization to get Raw Data from Unity Analytics. The Unity Dashboard are changing again and again and I am not sure that I get the right credentials.
Is this proper key to get basic authentication through HTML something? Like ProjectID and this API Key?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the rather obvious create api key next to the highlighted box?

Comment: I have one created (numbers hide by rectangle) so do you think I should generate new?

Comment: Then no. Use the ones you have

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by just joining Beta Unity Gaming Analytics program. Magic. Now I have Analytics Settings button and there I have proper key...

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, it's easily found at an old URL:

https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/projects/YOUR-PROJECT-ID-HERE/edit/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34090143)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).